# Why I cannot update the data when I use GormV2?

Tags: go, go-gorm

When using GormV1 these codes are working. But when upgrading to GormV2 it seems that the column is not exist.
I think it's because the entered key doesn't match and it can't find the column I want to update.
but I send a single word key it can be added to db eg. nationality, language but if I send key from frontend as acceptFriends, fontSize throws the following error:

SQL Error [42703]ERROR: column "acceptFriends" of relation "users" does not exist

// frontend

```
 const chooseAutoAccept = (event) => {
    let value = event.value.toString(); // true or false
    updateProfile("acceptFriends", value);
  };
```

// backend
// Model User use

```
type User struct {
    Model
    Nationality   string        `json:"nationality"` // working
    AcceptFriends types.Boolean `json:"acceptFriends" gorm:"type:varchar(5)"` // not working
    FontSize      FontSize      `json:"fontSize" gorm:"default:'md'"` // not working
    Language      string        `json:"language" gorm:"default:'EN'"` // working
}
```

// User_service

```
func (ctx userServiceCtx) UpdateUserProfile(userUpdate dto.UserUpdate) (out models.User, err error) {
    user := models.User{}
    //1. find by ID
    if err := ctx.db.First(&user, "id=?", userUpdate.ID).Error; err != nil {
        return out, err
    }
    //2. set new data and update
    for _, item := range userUpdate.Data {
        // item.Key = "acceptFriends", item.Value = true or false
        if err := ctx.db.Model(&user).Update(item.Key, item.Value).Error; err != nil {
            return out, err
        }
    }
    return user, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to take a look at this. From what I can read from the gorm documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions), It looks like, as the field names `AcceptFriends` and `FontSize` will be converted to `accept_friends` and `font_size` as a column names in db.

When you call the `Update` method you need to call it with correct column name, in the case of AcceptFriends it should be `accept_friends` not `acceptFriends` as the column name.

I hope this helps.